# Why don't pets seem to talk to humans in the Harry Potter universe?

Tags: harry-potter

Most of us know that in the Harry Potter universe pets serve as close companions and friends of witches and wizards. They are also faithful assisting with sending and bringing mail and, out-of-universe, they serve as comic relief in the plot; but they don't seem to talk to humans.

Regarding animals talking to humans, it is well known that snakes use Parseltongue language. A ferret called Jarvey can talk. There is an interesting case of pet-to-Animagus talking: Crookshanks is seen in *Prisoner of Azkaban* talking to Padfoot in the school grounds.

It has been well demonstrated in the universe that non-talking pets work very well. With the exception of Hagrid's pet Acromantula Aragog, I'm curious if the Canon or J.K. Rowling herself has explain about why pets don't seem to talk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because they are not capable of human speech.

The creatures that are (e.g. centaurs, goblins, acromantula, giants, merpeople, manticores) generally don't want to be pets. Jarveys (which are not actually ferrets) appear to be an exception, but according to their FBaWTFT entry you can't have a discussion with one because it just insults you and runs away.

All the owls, cat, toads, rats, and snakes are just animals. The only way they can talk to humans is if the human has the ability to talk to them. But as we are told, Parselmouths and Animagi are pretty rare.

Comment: Thank you, OrangeDog. I believe your brief answer is useful to me.